# How to insert into a database some information that can be the same that another row?

Tags: php, mysql, database, duplicates

Like, I have a row contain this [information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Gdj7.png). The hidden column determine if it’s visible in research (0) or not (1).

I want to insert a new row with similar info (especially same name) of the row with `hidden number =1`. But right now, if I insert same info of a computer that have an `hidden number = 1` (like `IT-Melanie`), it will only ‘refresh’ the row already there, not created a new one! It’s there a possibility to create a new row with the same name (like `IT-Melanie`), but with maybe some differents other infos to insert without this update the already existing row? It’s like if we duplicate a row in the database, but with all the same information.

The only think I found here it's duplicate a row in javascript and it's not I want. I try to insert more than a time information to have two rows similar without success, only an update of the row already present in database!

Recap : I want insert a new computer with same name of one already existing in the database, but the old one will have an `hidden number = 1` and the new one `= 0`.

Question : Can we put two row with the same `computer_name` without editing the old row?

Example :

Old row : `Computer_name` = `It_melanie`
          `product_number`= `xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx`
           [...]
           `hidden`=`1`

New row : `Computer_name` = `It_melanie`
          `product_number`= `xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx`
           [...]
           `hidden`=`0`

[Unique Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqQHy.png)

My code

```
    //Get informations in the form and insert it into db
    $location=$_GET['location'];
    $dept=$_GET['dept'];
    $jack=$_GET['jack'];
    $computername=$_GET['computername'];
    $productkey=$_GET['productkey'];
    $model=$_GET['model'];
    $vendor=$_GET['vendor'];
    $serialnumber=$_GET['serialnumber'];
    $macaddress=$_GET['macaddress'];
    $status=$_GET['status'];
    $starphone=$_GET['starphone'];
    $intid=$_GET['intid'];
    $did=$_GET['did'];
    $software=$_GET['software'];
    $query='insert into department(
    department,
    location_id)values(
    "'.$dept.'",
    "'.$location.'")';
    if(valid_query($query)){
    $message .= "Enregistrement a ete mis a jour<br>";
    }else{
            $message .= "Enregistrement n a pas ete mis a jour! S'il vous plait contacter le Departement TI IOS<br>";
    }
    $query='insert into computer(
    computer_name,
    product_key,
    model,
    serial_number,
    status_id,
    starphone,
    inst_id,
    did,
    macaddress,
    software_id,
    hidden
    )values(
    "'.$computername.'",
    "'.$productkey.'",
    "'.$model.'",
    "'.$serialnumber.'",
    "'.$status.'",
    "'.$starphone.'",
    "'.$intid.'",
    "'.$did.'",
    "'.$macaddress.'",
    "'.$software.'",
    0
    )';
    if(valid_query($query)){
    $message .= "Enregistrement a ete mis a jour<br>";
    }else{
            $message .= "Enregistrement n a pas ete mis a jour! S'il vous plait contacter le Departement TI IOS<br>";
    }
    $query="select dept_id from department where department='$dept' and location_id='$location'";
    $deptid=select_query($query);
    $query="select computer_id from computer where computer_name ='$computername'";
    $computerid=select_query($query);
    $query='insert into jack(
    jack_number,
    dept_id,
    location_id,
    computer_id
    )values(
    "'.$jack.'",
    "'.$deptid.'",
    "'.$location.'",
    "'.$computerid.'")';
    if(valid_query($query)){
    $message .= "Enregistrement a ete mis a jour<br>";
    }else{
            $message .= "Enregistrement n a pas ete mis a jour! S'il vous plait contacter le Departement TI IOS<br>";
    }

    $query='insert into computer_vendor(
    computer_id,
    vendor_id
    )values(
    "'.$computerid.'",
    "'.$vendor.'")';
    if(valid_query($query)){
    $message .= "Enregistrement a ete mis a jour<br>";
    }else{
            $message .= "Enregistrement n a pas ete mis a jour! S'il vous plait contacter le Departement TI IOS<br>";
    }
    $location="";
    $dept="";
    $jack="";
    $computername="";
    $productkey="";
    $model="";
    $vendor="";
    $serialnumber="";
    $macaddress="";
    $status="";
    $starphone="";
    $intid="";
    $did="";
```

Comment: you have to remove unique constraints from each column in table then possible you can add that

Comment: It's not an issue with your code, it's an issue with the table. Check the unique constraints on your table, and check the unique primary key. Insure that `hidden` is part of the key. It also sounds odd that your code is causing an UPDATE on primary key duplication inserts. I would think it would just error. I see no UPDATE, DELETE, or other SQL that would suggest upsert logic.

Comment: I suppose it's in relation with the new image i just add above? (unique key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure that the **column computer_name is not marked as *UNIQUE***.
-To do that connect to MySQL through Terminal or cmd or any shell, login in the database where the table is. (run `mysql -u <mysql_user> -p <db_name>`) Then use `DESCRIBE <table_name>;` and in the column with value *Key* check is *computer_name*'s value is *UNI* - this means that it is marked as *UNIQUE*. Example result: [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7RA6.png)

Second, **remove the *UNIQUE* constraint from the column**.

-To do that (while you are still connected to MySQL through shell and you are still in the same database) use `ALTER TABLE <table_name> DROP INDEX computer_name;`.
Third, check did you succeed.
-Again use `DESCRIBE <table_name>;` and if there is still a value *UNI* in the *Key* column do step 2 again.
Good luck.